# Would moving files across folders and renaming folders many times affect the performance & speed of a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, files-folders

To organize digital content, I move around files and folders many times (within the same external hard drive), as well as rename folders too. Would this affect the performance specially speed of the hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't.
All it's doing is moving a pointer. The files themselves don't move anywhere, just the address to them is updated.

Comment: In FAT-type file systems directory entries will be rewritten at the new location and deleted at the old location.